# android studio get Current location with googleapiclient

Tags: android, android-studio

I've some difficulties to get gps position in my android app.

in manifest.xml i put:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

in my Activity Class the fragment code:

```
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    try {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    } catch (SecurityException secEx) {

    }

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        String mLatitudeText = new String(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        String mLongitudeText = new String(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
```

methods overriden (empty because I don't know if I should write some other code inside):

```
    @Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    try {
        if (mLastLocation == null) {
            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        }
    } catch (SecurityException secEx) {

    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

The mLastLocation is null!

Any ideas?
Take a look to the APP permissions on bottom image.

[image]

Comment: was ur googleapi client connected successfullY?

Comment: Yes @SouravGanguly, it connects successfully

Comment: can you print the stack trace.. security exception. it must be giving some error. and also u have included the google-services.json file and other settings properly?

Comment: `getLastLocation()` would return null if previously there hasn't been received any location. Once you receive a location, next time it will return normal `LatLng` object.

Comment: @azizbekian , so how reiceve location correctly for first time?

Comment: have you override onConnected(){} ?

Comment: yes, @AkshayTilekar, but it is empty because I dont know what I should write inside.

Comment: @SouravGanguly I get no error, no stacktrace avaiable...

Comment: @michael, have you implemented `LocationListener` interface? You will received location in `onLocationChanged()` callback. Have a glance on [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java) code.

Comment: actual logic to get last known location

Comment: @michael see answer wch i have posted

Comment: what is the api level of your app?

Comment: @AkshayTilekar, 25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to override **onConnected** method,Once you have connected to Google Play services and the location services API, you can get the last known location of a user's device. When your app is connected to these you can use the fused location provider's getLastLocation() method to retrieve the device location. The precision of the location returned by this call is determined by the permission setting you put in your app manifest, as described in the Specify App Permissions section of this document.

To request the last known location, call the getLastLocation() method, passing it your instance of the GoogleApiClient object. Do this in the onConnected() callback provided by Google API Client, which is called when the client is ready. The following code snippet illustrates the request and a simple handling of the response:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            String mLatitudeText = mLastLocation.getLatitude());
            String mLongitudeText= mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        }
    }
}
```

for more,refer this : https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

**Note :**

> if you are using API 23 and above try to find the problem by
>   downgrading from API to 22. Android 6.0 apparently doesn't produce any
>   error message when permissions fail.

Comment: it seems to not enter in onConnected method by view debug

Comment: @michael refer the link provided in answer

Comment: which API you are using for app?

Comment: See updated question and take a look to the permissions. The app grant all needed ones.

Answer (score 1):

If the API level is >=23 then you need to check for permissions and if not you need to grant it. Like this,

```
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ...},200);
        return;
    }


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode==200){
        if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        //your work
    }
}
```

Do this after onConntected method fired and also try the get the location after onConnected
if this does not work, to see the error please print the stacktrace on catch.